# Setting NumbroJS culture

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to change numbro's culture. I've tried the simple way, but got an error:

```
Unknown culture : ' + code numbro.culture('fr-FR');
```

I tried like this:

```
const br = require('numbro/languages/pt-BR') numbro.culture('pt-BR', br)
```

but nothing changes and the default culture is applied.. Can anyone give me a hand?

Or please suggest another option besides numbro. I was trying NumeralJS, but It had the same problem and the project seems a little dead.

**Edit**

Here a full example:

```
 <script src="/numbro/languages.min.js"></script>

var numbro = require('numbro');
const br = require('numbro/languages/pt-BR')
numbro.culture('pt-BR')
console.log('teste ' + numbro(1234.56).format('$0,0.00'));
```

Comment: Please supply a bit more detail: add a bit more code. Also, I just checked on [this link](http://numbrojs.com/languages.html), `languages.js` needs to be included. Did you include it?

Comment: and I've already included both `languages` and `numbro` :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about numbro culture, but there is setLanguage:

```
const numbro = require('numbro');
const lang = require('./node_modules/numbro/dist/languages.min.js');

numbro.registerLanguage(lang['de-DE']);
numbro.setLanguage( 'de-DE' );
// prints 1234.56 ( my locale is en_US.UTF-8 )
console.log( numbro.unformat('€1.234,56' ) );
```